# Getting expression tree from scripting language in c#

Tags: c#, ironpython, expression-trees

I am looking for a way to generate an expression tree from a script in C#. Currently, I am using IronPython, but I am open to switching if it would make it easier to get the expression tree. Also, I realize that I could get this from implementing my own scripting language; however, I would rather use one that is already created if possible.

If a scripting language besides IronPython is recommended, I need it to have: if statements (preferably with and/or), mathematical operations (+,-,*,/,log,%,^), loops, and the ability to add custom functions.

As an example of what I am trying to do, I have included two blocks of code.One calculates the bonus using an expression tree that is created and then compiled:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee() { Salary = 100000, BonusPct = .05 };
            Expression<Func<Employee, double>> calcbonusExp = x => x.Salary * x.BonusPct; ;
            var calcBonus = calcbonusExp.Compile();
            Console.WriteLine(calcBonus(employee));
            Console.WriteLine(calcbonusExp.NodeType);
            Console.WriteLine(calcbonusExp.Body);
            Console.WriteLine(calcbonusExp.Body.NodeType);
            foreach (var param in calcbonusExp.Parameters)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(param.Name);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
}

public class Employee
    {
        public double Salary { get; set; }
        public double BonusPct { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The other calculates the bonus using IronPython:

```
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;
using System;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee() { Salary = 100000, BonusPct = .05 };

            ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
            ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();

            ScriptSource source = engine.Execute(
                @"def calcBonus(employee):
                      return employee.Salary * employee.BonusPct 
                ", scope);
            var calcAdd = scope.GetVariable("calcBonus");
            var result = calcAdd(employee);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public double Salary { get; set; }
        public double BonusPct { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get the same expression tree out of the block of code using IronPython (or any other scripting language)?

Comment: The second example doesn't really create an expression tree per se. It creates a delegate. The common element here is that you are creating a delegate and invoking it. Is that what you are really after? Because there is a [scripting API](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples) that can effectively do that. Expression trees are more about representing code as data that can be inspected and analyzed, but that's not what the second example does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Roslyn to create an Expression object from a script written in C# or VB.

See e.g. https://www.strathweb.com/2018/01/easy-way-to-create-a-c-lambda-expression-from-a-string-with-roslyn/